# ObserveEvent doesn't run the code the way I'd like it to

Tags: shiny

I would like to make sure that when we click on the button **button** we **send** in the verbatimTextOutput, **1** then we **pause for 2s** and at the end we send **2**.
But what **I get** is a **pause for 2s** then it sends **1** and **2**.

How can I do that ?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE),
  actionButton("b", "button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  o  <- reactiveVal("--- Hello ---")

  output$output <- renderText(o())

  observeEvent(input$b, {

    o(c(o(), "\n", "- 1 "))
    Sys.sleep(2)
    o(c(o(), "\n", "- 2 "))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE),
  actionButton("b", "button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v  <- reactiveValues(msg = "--- Hello ---",start = 0)

  output$output <- renderText({
    v$msg
  })

  observeEvent(input$b,{
    v$msg <- paste0(v$msg,"\n","- 1 ")
    v$start <- v$start + 1
  })

  start <- reactive({
    v$start
  })

  start_d <- start %>% debounce(50)

  observeEvent(start_d(),{
    req(start_d() > 0)
    Sys.sleep(2)
    v$msg <- paste0(v$msg,"\n","- 2 ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. Can you explain what the line *start_d <- start %>% debounce(50)* do exactly ?

Comment: `debounce` simply delays the firing of the reactive. You probably noticed that most things are bound together when inside observer or reactive expression as `apply` family of functions are used. This will enable separation. I could have also used the `promises` library but I dont think its necessary here

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do with delay() from shinyjs

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE),
    actionButton("b", "button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    o  <- reactiveVal("--- Hello ---")

    output$output <- renderText(o())

    observeEvent(input$b, {
        o(c(o(), "\n", "- 1 "))
        delay(2000, o(c(o(), "\n", "- 2 ")))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As you dont know how long the function will take to complete, you cannot really use it in this context

Comment: Hello, thank for your help, i use sys.sleep for simulate a download. I connect in ssh and download a folder on the remote machine. I got the code from M. @Pork Chop.